# How to determine and print jQuery version?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a jQuery function that returns the version of jQuery that is currently loaded?

Comment: after reading all answers, `$.fn.jquery` will do it :p

Comment: For the $() method I get, "$() is undefined", let me try the other method.

Comment: James - Are you certain that you have the jQuery library loaded before you run the `$().jquery` ?

Comment: Yeah I take it back, it's an xhtml/jsf issue, where it doesn't like the $, when replaced by jQuery both methods work.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

You can use this:

```
$.fn.jquery
//or if you're using .noConflict():
jQuery.fn.jquery
```

It's updated automatically when jQuery is built, defined here: http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L174

Make sure to use `$.fn.property` for properties that don't depend on an object, no reason to create an unneeded jquery object with `$().property` unless you intend to use it :)

Answer (score 22):

```
alert( $.fn.jquery )
```

Answer (score 13):

I'm not sure how many versions of jQuery this exists in, but a jQuery object has a `jquery` property that stores the version.

```
alert( $().jquery );
```

Will alert `1.4.2` if you're using that version.

Answer (score 12):

```
$().jquery;
```

This will return a string containing the jQuery version

Answer (score 11):

```
$().jquery; // yields the string "1.4.2", for example
```

Source: http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/02/how-to-check-jquery-version.html

Answer (score 10):

try

```
alert($().jquery)
```

Answer (score 0):

Alert is good, but if you want to actually print the jquery version...

```
<script>
document.write($.fn.jquery);
</script>
```