# Same jQuery code returns two different results – Submit Button Text

Tags: jquery

I have two `jQuery` codes - http://jsfiddle.net/Lijo/CXGX7/7/ and http://jsfiddle.net/Lijo/CXGX7/8/ . The first code returns `undefined` whereas the second code returns text of button.

**QUESTIONS**

1. What is the reason for this difference in result?
2. Why is the first code not returning expected text of button?

Note: I verified that both are using same `version` of jQuery (by an alert of jQuery)

```
alert($.fn.jquery);
```

**CODE**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><title>

</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.8.1.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    alert($('.myButton').attr("value"));

</script>

</head>
<body>

<form method="post" action="Test.aspx" id="form1">
<div class="aspNetHidden">
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwULLTE0MDM4MzYxMjNkZMycQvsYQ+GPFsQHoQ8j/8vEo2vQbqkhfgPc60kxXaQO" />
</div>

<div class="aspNetHidden">

<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="/wEWAwKqxqqrCgLi/JazDQKM54rGBqgaroRQTXJkD1LyUlVxAmLRCNfTGVe73swQBMemBtvN" />
</div>
<div>

    <input name="txtEmpName" type="text" id="txtEmpName" />

    <input type="submit" name="Button1" value="Submit" id="Button1" class="myButton" />
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

REFERENCES

1. [Retrieve Button value with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487056/retrieve-button-value-with-jquery)
2. [How to determine and print jQuery version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3240296/how-to-determine-and-print-jquery-version)

Comment: Because in the first version, when your script loads, your button isn't loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because in the first version, when your script executes, the button is probably not yet loaded in the DOM.

In [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Lijo/CXGX7/7/) version, you are writing `alert` directly in the html page. So, when that portion of the page is loaded in the browser, it will be executed immediately. At this point, the rest of your page is not loaded, so your `$('.myButton')` selector will return nothing (you can check it by `$('.myButton').length`).

In [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Lijo/CXGX7/8/) version, you are writing this code inside the `JavaScript` panel of JsFiddle. The JS code that you write in here runs inside an `onload` event handler, which ensures that all of your html has been loaded before executing any JS code inside it.

So, in the first version, your code is converted to something like this -

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    alert($.fn.jquery);
});
```

and for the second version -

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    alert($('.myButton').attr("value"));
    alert($.fn.jquery);
});
```

**Edit**

The `$(document).ready()` function is called whenever DOM is fully loaded in the browser. You pass a callback function as an argument to this function which will be called when it happens. Usually, anything you want to do with jQuery, you do it inside that callback. This is the very first thing to learn about jQuery. You can get an official tutorial about it [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials%3aIntroducing_%24%28document%29.ready%28%29).

This method is somewhat similar to [window.onload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onload), except that it fires as soon as your HTML document has been loaded, and `window.onload` is called after all the contents of a page(including images and other resources) has been fully loaded.

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense. I corrected it using `document.ready` http://jsfiddle.net/Lijo/CXGX7/11/. Also, it would be great if you can mention about `document.ready` in your answer

Answer (score 1):

Because

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   // some code to run as soon as possible
</script>
```

is not like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){
         // some code to run when all page is ready
     }):
</script>
```

This is [How JQuery works](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials%3aHow_jQuery_Works)

Answer (score 0):

Your button is not added in DOM when you called `alert()` in your first sample.
Use `ready()` callback function:

```
$(function(){alert($('.myButton').attr("value"));});
```